# Efficiently removing duplicate @Mapping annotations for audit fields in MapStruct Spring Core

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

There are ways how can I remove the same ignore mapping without reapeated @Mapping annotations on different methods, for example audit fields in one short annotation or interface like IgnoreMappingAuditionFields or other ways?
So what ways you can recommend for resolve this problem?

```
@Mapper(config = MapperConfiguration.class)
public interface CategoryMapper {
    CategoryDto toDto(final Category category);

    @Mapping(target = "createdAt", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "updatedAt", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "createdBy", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "modifiedBy", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "quizzes", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "parentCategory.createdAt", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "parentCategory.updatedAt", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "parentCategory.createdBy", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "parentCategory.modifiedBy", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "parentCategory.id", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "parentCategory.quizzes", ignore = true)
    Category toCategory(final CategoryDto categoryDto);

    @Mapping(target = "createdAt", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "updatedAt", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "createdBy", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "modifiedBy", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "quizzes", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "parentCategory.createdAt", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "parentCategory.updatedAt", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "parentCategory.createdBy", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "parentCategory.modifiedBy", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "parentCategory.id", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "parentCategory.quizzes", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "parentCategory", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "childCategories", ignore = true)
    Category toDomain(final CategoryCreationRequest categoryCreationRequest);
}
```

Remove repeated fields

Comment: does your IDE show a warningabout the duplication?

Comment: @eduyayo no my IDE doesnt show warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to group together multiple mapping annotations into a custom annotation. For example, you can create an annotation for ignoring audit mappings:

```java
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Mapping(target = "createdAt", ignore = true)
@Mapping(target = "updatedAt", ignore = true)
@Mapping(target = "createdBy", ignore = true)
@Mapping(target = "modifiedBy", ignore = true)
public @interface IgnoreAuditMapping {}
```

The annotation can be used in mappers to reduce duplication:

```
@Mapper(config = MapperConfiguration.class)
public interface CategoryMapper {
    ...

    @IgnoreAuditMapping
    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "quizzes", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "parentCategory.createdAt", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "parentCategory.updatedAt", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "parentCategory.createdBy", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "parentCategory.modifiedBy", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "parentCategory.id", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "parentCategory.quizzes", ignore = true)
    Category toCategory(final CategoryDto categoryDto);

    ...
}
```